# Can viewDidLoad be called mutiple times?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The documentation says "This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory."  My questions are:

1) if I initialize a view controller is viewDidLoad called, or does the view actually have to be added as a superview of the current view for it to be called

2) If I add the view controllers view, and viewDidLoad is called, then I remove the view controllers view, then re-add it again later, will viewDidLoad be called again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called whenever the view is loaded. This happens when the `vc.view` property is accessed. It typically happens right before adding the view to a view hierarchy, but it can happen earlier if the property is accessed earlier.

If you remove your view from a view hierarchy, and then a memory warning happens and `viewDidUnload` is called, then `viewDidLoad` will be called again if the `view` property is accessed again. But this is the only way for it to be called a second time; if your view never unloads, then `viewDidLoad` will never be repeated.